# Comparing Dates For Multiple Entries

Tags: mysql, date, compare

im creating a small hire car system and i want a stored procedure that takes in a date and checks to see which cars are available then. I've got the compare working but if a car has more than one contract and one of the contracts isn't for the entered date but another is it says the car is available. Below is my procedure so far

```
delimiter //

create procedure allAvailableVehicles(req varchar(15))    
BEGIN

select distinct vehicles.vehicleID as "Vehicle ID", vehicles.Make as "Make", vehicles.Model as "Model" from vehicles

left outer join contracts
on vehicles.vehicleID=contracts.vehicleID
where cast(req as date) not between hiredFrom and hiredUntill
or contractID is unknown
order by vehicles.vehicleID;

end
//    
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to use `not exists`:

```
select v.*
from vehicles v
where not exists (select 1
                  from contracts c
                  where c.VehicleId = v.VehicleId and
                        cast(req as date) between hiredFrom and hiredUntil
                 );
```

Note:  you should not need to cast `req` as a date, because it should already be stored as a date in the database (unless `req` also has a time component).

A better way to write the stored procedure is:

```
delimiter //

create procedure allAvailableVehicles(p_req date)
begin
  select v.*
  from vehicles v
  where not exists (select 1
                    from contracts c
                    where c.VehicleId = v.VehicleId and
                          p_req between hiredFrom and hiredUntil
                   );
  end //

  delimiter ;
```

Use built-in types for date/times.  Also, name your parameters to distinguish them from columns.